# Curl 405 error when attempting a website login

Tags: cookies, curl, authentication, web, passwords

I am attempting to use curl to monitor a substitute teacher job posting site. I originally started with wget and have since moved to attempting this with curl. I have done some searching but have not been able to find any good documentation to how to fix my problem. Currently as soon as I try to login to the website and save the cookie I get a 405 Method Not Allowed error.

Reading through the documentation all I can come up with is this

> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.

Not being too familiar with any web related code I am not sure on how to proceed with fixing this issue.

Here is my current code:

> echo start
>
> curl  -d "LastName=XXXXXXX&PinNumber=XXXXXXXXX" -c cookies.txt https://subfinder.smusd.org/webconnect/login/loginpage.asp
>
> echo middle
>
> curl -b cookies.txt https://subfinder.smusd.org/webconnect/Sub/SubAvailableJobs.asp > BLAH
>
> echo end
>
> exit;

Here is the error I get

> start
>   Method not allowed
>
> ## HTTP/1.1 405 Method not allowed
>
> middle
>    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                   Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>   100   121  100   121    0     0    210      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   278
>   end

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is what I would expect to see on a POST to the wrong URL. Are you
sure you're posting to the right location?

Comment: I recorded the headers using Mozilla's Live HTTP Headers. I took the url straight out of that. Here is the the [Live HTTP Headers](http://pastebin.com/GfMjDu8E)  (Pastebin because it would not fit in the comments)